# URL parameters not being recognised

Tags: php

I have the URL example.com/view/index.php?id=12345 and within the index page I have:

```
<?

    $identity = $_GET['id'];
    // print $_GET['id']; returns nothing either
    print $identity;

?>
```

The problem I have is that the value isn't being retrieved and my error logs are clear. Any ideas?

Comment: what does print_r($_REQUEST) show you?

Comment: It's better to use **echo** because it is **10 times** faster than **print**.

Comment: @DrewP84 I'm given a blank page.

Comment: Which PHP version are you using? The INI setting [variables_order](http://php.net/manual/ini.core.php#ini.variables-order) must at least contain the character "G" to propagate the superglobal $_GET.

Comment: Have a look at the generated HTML. Is the PHP code still displayed?

Comment: Does `echo "hello world";` work? If not, see Oswald's answer.

Comment: I'm using PHP Version 5.5.3-1ubuntu2, the `short_open_tag` option was disabled by default for some reason. All works now, thank you for the fast response!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The configuration option [`short_open_tag`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) is disabled.

Don't enable `short_open_tag`; you can never be sure whether you will have control over the PHP configuration of the host that your script will be executed on. Rewrite your script instead.

Since PHP 5.4, the `<?= $var ?>` notation for printing works despite disabled `short_open_tag`.

Comment: I was just lucky that the problem was described accurately enough.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is wrong Try
    var_dump($_GET);